# Open mmenu Submenu directly

Tags: jquery, mmenu

is there any chance to open a specific submenu by a link or click? In this example, it would be nice to skip the first level and **jump directly to the "About us" section** when the menu opens?

I have not tried anything yet, because I don't know what to try. Sorry, my skills are not the best. That is why I would appreciate your help very much! Thanks.

```
<nav id="menu">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About us</a>
           <ul>
              <li><a href="/about/history">History</a></li>
              <li><a href="/about/team">The team</a></li>
              <li><a href="/about/address">Our address</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: If you don't try anything, your question if off-topic. Because instead of asking for help on how to code you're asking for code. It's the difference between being a programmer and a client.

Comment: I know, but I am my client. I don't want to waste anyone's time. Just asking for help.